# Grub 2 detects incorrect partition for windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Windows 7 is present on /dev/sda3, but grub 2 detects Windows 7 on /dev/sda1. How can I configure Grub 2 so that it will always point to /dev/sda3 for Windows 7, even if later on I do a `sudo update-grub`?

Windows 7 is present on sda3, but during installation it created a small 100mb partition as sda1, which Grub 2 is pointing to. But Windows 7 on my machine can boot from /dev/sda3, not /dev/sda1.

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall the cinnamon installed by using the following command,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Once you are done with the above please proceed with login and logout else restart.

Comment: Thanks, but before I tried this, I updated Windows, and now it works. Strange, I'm not sure why, but it just seems to be working.

Comment: If by `cinnamon` you mean the desktop environment, it has nothing to do with boot loaders.